# ¿Que cardinalidad debe de tener esta relación?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy diseñando una base de datos sobre una tienda online. Las entidades serían usuarios, pedidos, productos y categorías. Quiero que un producto pueda tener una o varias categorías, pero no estoy seguro de la cardinalidad que existiría en productos.

Sería PRODUCTOS(1,N)----contiene----CATEGORÍAS(1,M) 
o PRODUCTOS(1,1)----contiene----CATEGORÍAS(1,M)?

Yo me he planteado la siguiente cuestión: "Varias categorias puede contener producto 1 y 2?" "-Si, por lo tanto cardinalidad (1,n) en productos".

Pero a lo mejor me equivoco no sé...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que en realidad sería que una Categoría puede contener n Productos y un Producto puede pertenecer a m Categorías, por tanto sería n a n. Es decir,  necesitarás una tabla de relación entre categorías y productos.

Comment: Si, estaba en lo cierto, ya que categoría 1 y 3 por ejemplo, puede estar en 1 o varios productos.